# Specific selector in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm learning jQuery and get stuck in a problem of selector.

I've got a function that hide and show element but I'm trying to apply it **precisely to the element click instead of to all the element.**

I tried with `$(this)` but I guess I was not specific enough.

Here is the **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10030/)**

And this is the function

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if($('.resume').text().length > 100)
    {
        complet = $('.resume').text();
        complet += '<span class="showLess"> Cacher</span>';
        html = $('.resume').text().slice(0,100);
        html += '<span class="showMore">...</span>';
        $('.resume').html(html);
    }

    $(document).on('click','.showMore', function(){
        $('.resume').html(complet);
        showLess();
    });

    function showLess(){
    $('.showLess').on('click', function() {
        $('.resume').html(html);
    });
    }

});
```

If someone can indicate me where shall I head ? closest ?

Comment: You don't even have anything that calls showLess()?

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong here. You need to go over all your `resume` elements with an `each` to check if they need a reed more / read less button. You don't need to call your `showLess` function each time, just add a `$(document).on('click','.showLess'...` instead of hte click handler you have now. Further you need to target the `parent` of `$(this)` to change the HTML.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz ?? Look the Fiddle

Comment: @putvande Thank you this is a productive answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple problems here....

1. You need to find the content/less for each resume element separately
2. The show less handler can be added using event delegation

So

```js
/* Maël check : Marche presque */
jQuery(function () {
    $('.resume').each(function () {
        var text = $(this).text();
        if (text.length > 100) {
            var less = text.slice(0, 100) + '<span class="showMore">...</span>';
            $(this).html(less);

            $(this).data('content', text + '<span class="showLess"> Cacher</span>')
            $(this).data('less', less)
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.showMore', function () {
        var $res= $(this).closest('.resume');
        $res.html($res.data('content'));
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.showLess', function () {
        var $res= $(this).closest('.resume');
        $res.html($res.data('less'));
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="resume">Bonjour je suis un gros Chat. Bonjour je suis un gros Chat. Bonjour je suis un gros Chat Bonjour je suis un gros Chat Bonjour je suis un gros Chat Bonjour je suis un gros Chat Bonjour je suis un gros Chat Bonjour je suis un gros Chat</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="resume">Cette fois ci un poisson ! Cette fois ci un poisson ! Cette fois ci un poisson ! Cette fois ci un poisson ! Cette fois ci un poisson !</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I have a look on everything and came back here if I have a question if its ok with you :)

Answer (score 2):

I would have done it like this:

```
$('.resume').each(function() {
    var resume = $(this),
        text = resume.text();

    if (text.length > 100) {
        var showLess = '<span class="showLess"> Cacher</span>',
            showMore = '<span class="showMore">...</span>',
            sliced = text.slice(0, 100);

        resume.html(sliced + showMore);

        resume.on('click', '.showLess', function() {
            resume.html(sliced + showMore);
        }); 

        resume.on('click', '.showMore', function() {
            resume.html(text + showLess);
        });        
    }
});
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10032/)